# What's the best way to restructure a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm restructuring an object in javascript to turn a flat object:

```
{
    'we' : 'are',
    'the' : 'knights',
    'who' : 'say',
    'ni' : '!!!'
}
```

into an object in which some of the items previously in the flat object are contained in a child of the original flat object:

```
{
    'we' : 'are',
    'the' : 'knights',
    'shrubbery' : {
        'who' : 'say',
        'ni' : '!!!'
    }
}
```

I can do this restructuring by referencing an then deleting, like so:

```
var knights = {
    'we' : 'are',
    'the' : 'knights',
    'who' : 'say',
    'ni' : '!!!'
};

knights.shrubbery = {'who':knights.who,
                     'ni':knights.ni};

delete knights.who;
delete knights.ni;
```

but this seems inelegant. Is there a better way to move attributes of one object to a different object or otherwise bundle attributes of an object into a child of that object?

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is form a flat object into a data tree, in which the root root object can contain groups which contain subgroups and so on. Something like turning this:

```
{'leaf1':'',
 'leaf2':'',
 'leaf3':'',
 'leaf4':'',
 'leaf5':'',
 'leaf6':'',
 'leaf7':'',
 'leaf8':'',
 'leaf9':''
}
```

into this:

```
{'leaf1':'',
 'leaf2':'',
 'leaf3':'',
 'groups' : [
     {
         'leaf1':''
     },{
     'leaf1':'',
     'leaf2':'',
     'groups':[
         {
         'leaf7':'',
         'leaf8':'',
         'leaf9':''
         }
     ]
     }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example in which context you're trying to do so? The question at this moment is highly opinion based.

Comment: Why is this inelegant? You could just move this into a function that accepts parameters and uses those parameters instead of specifically hardcoding the values in, but it would achieve the same thing

Comment: I'm just used to `jquery.append`, where I can append a DOM element to another and the element no longer exists in its origional location. I was wondering if there was something similar in javascript for moving attributes around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your current method, but to make it a bit more extensible you could wrap it in a function:

```
function restructure(obj, new_child, properties) {
    obj[new_child] = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        obj[new_child][properties[i]] = obj[properties[i]];
        delete obj[properties[i]];
    }
}

restructure(knights, 'shrubbery', ['who', 'ni']);
```

Comment: Ended up doing something similar; I extended the Object class with a new method that would do the appending for me. `Object.prototype.appendAttrTo = function(attr, target){target[attr] = this[attr];delete this[attr]}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing a method to do something like this in the general case. I wouldn't recommend mutating the object in place, just because more often than not you'll get more use out of one that creates a copy instead.

Here's an idea: how about the method signature takes:

1. An object
2. A property name
3. A list of property names to nest inside the new property

Like this:

```
function nestProperties(obj, property, nestedProperties)
{
  var newObj = {};
  var nestedObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < nestedProperties.length; ++i)
  {
    if (nestedProperties[i] in obj)
    {
      nestedObj[nestedProperties[i]] = obj[nestedProperties[i]];
    }
  }

  for (var k in obj)
  {
    if (!(k in nestedObj))
    {
      newObj[k] = obj[k];
    }
  }

  newObj[property] = nestedObj;

  return newObj;
}
```

You would use this like so:

```
var flat = {
  'we' : 'are',
  'the' : 'knights',
  'who' : 'say',
  'ni' : '!!!'
};

var knights = nestProperties(flat, 'shrubbery', ['who', 'ni']);
```